# SonarQube7.0 : Two modules have the same id: ''. Each module must have a unique id

Tags: sonarqube, sap-commerce-cloud

I am not using any module sin my sonarqube setup, there are no projects created yet. When I start sonarqube for the first time using ant sonar .I got the error :

Two modules have the same id: ''. Each module must have a unique id.

I am using below configuration :

```
sonar.jdbc.url=http\://localhost\:9000
sonar.projectKey=org.mycompany.myproject
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
#Properties
#Mon Apr 16 12:51:32 IST 2018
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=${jacoco.base.dir}/reports/jacoco.exec
jacoco.lib.loc=${jacoco.base.dir}/agent
sonar.sources=src
sonar.language=java
standalone.javaoptions=-javaagent:${jacoco.lib.loc}/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths},append=true,excludes=com.google.*:com.sun.*:de.hybris.platform.* 
sonar.test.exclusions=**/testsrc/
jacoco.base.dir=C\:\\Test\\hybris\\data\\jacoco
sonar.binaries=classes
sonar.inclusions=**/*test*
sonar.tests=testsrc
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
```

Comment: How did you execute the analysis? I see you run `ant sonar`, but what was the working directory. Where did you create sonar properties configuration?